# Is there a difference between := and = with mysql variables?

Tags: mysql

Is there a difference between @var := 0;  and @var = 0; ?

With and without the colon?  What does that do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html), they are synonymous:

```
SET @var := 1234;
SET @var = 1234;
```

But `=` acts as a conditional operator when used in a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT @var := 1234; -- 1234
SELECT @var = 1234;  -- 1
```

So it's generally best to stick to `:=` for assignment to avoid confusion.